# Get HTTP Error code from requests.exceptions.HTTPError

Tags: python, http, exception, python-requests

I am catching exceptions like this,

```
def get_url_fp(image_url, request_kwargs=None):
    response = requests.get(some_url, **request_kwargs)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.raw


try:
   a = "http://example.com"
   fp = get_url_fp(a)

except HTTPError as e:
    # Need to check its an 404, 503, 500, 403 etc.
```

Comment: Maybe this post would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16206247/1461780

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The `HTTPError` carries the `Response` object with it:

```
def get_url_fp(image_url, request_kwargs=None):
    response = requests.get(some_url, **request_kwargs)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.raw


try:
    a = "http://example.com"
    fp = get_url_fp(a)

except HTTPError as e:
    # Need to check its an 404, 503, 500, 403 etc.
    status_code = e.response.status_code
```

Comment: one of the keys here is you also need to call response.raise_for_status(). reference here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes

Comment: Thanks a ton. 
Seems like this is the only way to handle errors in any HTTP methods using python `requests`.

Comment: Curious. I'm seeing e.response as an object of type urllib3.response.HTTPResponse.

Answer (score 8):

If you need only status_code or message error. You can use this code:

```
try:
  [YOUR CODE]
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
  print(err.response.status_code)
  print(err.response.text)
```

[Reference: Source code for requests.exceptions](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/requests/exceptions/)

Answer (score -10):

This is my code to get errors codes in HTTP

```
def tomcat_status(ip,port,url):
    try:
    # you can give your own url is
       r = urllib2.urlopen('http://'+ip+':'+port+'/'+url)
       return r.getcode()
     except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
       return e.code
    except urllib2.URLError as f:
       return 1
print tomcat_status(ip,tomcat_port,ping_url)
```

Comment: The OP was specific about using the Requests package. Your answer is using urllib2. While it may be technically accurate and represent an alternative way to do a thing it is not helpful in this context. It also appears to be poorly formatted.

Comment: This is just another alternative to get the Status code, as both request and urllib are default in python , we can use either of them.